# Phrase search-optimal index settings

Tags: indexing, marklogic, marklogic-8

The documentation for `word positions` and `fast phrase searches` both indicate improvements with phrase searches. Where do they overlap? If I enable `fast phrase searches` and have no intention of using `cts:near-query`, is `word positions` redundant for simply optimizing phrase searching?

Answer (score 2):

`fast phrase searches` will give you accurate results for two-word phrases, and more accurate results for longer phrases than just word searches. `word positions` will give you accurate results for longer phrases too. The trade off is that looking at positions takes time and memory, so if you mostly have two-word phrases, `fast phrase searches` is better, as it becomes a single term lookup.

Comment: What if the length of the phrases are arbitrary? Then would the word positions speed up the resolution of the combinations of 2-word phrases that make up the N-length phrase? Or does fast phrase maintain positions on its own?

Comment: The `word positions` will allow MarkLogic to resolve the correct order of longer phrases from indexes, so can return accurate results even when searching `unfiltered`. It is slower, but accurate, and likely faster than filtered searches.

Comment: @grtjn If I run an `unfiltered` search for the phrase "the quick brown fox" with only `fast phrase searches` (and not `word positions`), it sounds like that could return a false positive for a document containing the phrase "the quick man shot the brown fox" because search would be lacking the positional information to determine whether "the quick" and "brown fox" are from the same phrase. Is that correct?

Comment: MarkLogic will split in 3 duplets: `the quick`, `quick brown`, and `brown fox`. It could make a mistake if `quick brown` occurs in a different place, like in: `the quick man jumped the quick brown dog to shoot the brown fox`.